# Adjunct vs disjunct

Tags: terminology, adjuncts

What is the difference between an adjunct and disjunct?  How can I distinguish between the two?  Please, I will be very thankful if you give me some examples.

Comment: Are you asking about disjuncts or dis**ad**juncts? Please [edit] this to make your question consistent.

Comment: My question is clear enough. Please, do not try to invent what I did not write. Stick to my question which is disjunct.

Comment: There is no such thing as a disadjunct, so your question can't be answered as asked.

Comment: @user11223 **You** wrote disajunct in the title: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/revisions/15682/1 Don't get angry at us because you made a typo.

Answer (score 3):

**As is, your question has no answer**, since you haven't mentioned what theory or whose classification you were interested in. Here's what Hilde Hasselgård writes on this:

> "A striking feature of descriptions of adverbials is that there are hardly any two grammars that use the same classification scheme and/or terminology" (Hasselgård 2010: 21).

For more details on how different linguists classify adverbs, see [Hasselgård 2010](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/adjunct-adverbials-english?format=HB&isbn=9780521515566), especially [Part I.2. The classification of adverbials.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511676253.003)